# How can I map my data to add commas and spaces where needed?

Tags: reactjs

I am currently trying to map data but when I am trying to map it it displays

> KetogenicAlkalineFit for Life

I would like it to look like this when displaying:

> Ketogenic, Alkaline, Fit for Life

Here is where my data is first being mapped.\

```
render() {
const mealplanRecords = this.state.mealplanItems.map(mealplanItem => {
  return <MealplanItem mealplanItem={mealplanItem} />
})
  return (
      <div>
        <div className="mealplan-page-header">
          <h1>Newest Mealplans</h1>
          <hr />
        </div>
          <div className="content-container">
            {mealplanRecords}
          </div> 
      </div>
  )
```

}
}

And here is where it is displayed:

```
    const MealplanItem = props => {
    const {
        mealplan_name,
        mealplan_diets,
    } = props.mealplanItem
    return(
          <div>
            <div className="mealplan-card-wrapper">
              <div className="mealplan-card-name-wrapper">
                <h1 className="mealplan-name">{mealplan_name}</h1>
              </div>
              <div className="mealplan-diets-wrapper">
                <h1 className="Diets">Diets included: {mealplan_diets}</h1>
              </div>
              <div className="mealplan-button-wrapper">
                <button>To Plan</button> {/* This is where it will direct to the specific mealplan. (Needs to be done still) */}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    )
}
```

Here is the full set of data that is being given

https://pastebin.com/ydNrFLBW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <h1 className="Diets">Diets included: {mealplan_diets.join(', ')}</h1>
```

This will join each item in the array into a string "item1, item2, item3"